# Error when installing Tor Browser

Tags: tor-install

I am using Windows 7 Service pack 1, 64 bits.

I downloaded Tor (last version 6.5) on a oficial webpage.

I can't install program.

" Error opening file for writing : C:\Program Files (x86)\Tor Browser\Browser\AccesibleMarshall.dll

Click Abord to stop the installation 
Retry to try again, or 
Ignore to skip this file.

Thanks for your help and explanation.

Comment: Instead of discussing what an Operating System is supposed or not to do, provide answers that solve the problem, maybe pointing out their respective advantages and disadvantages. Users who encounter problems want a solution first, not a philosophical discussion about what you personally think is a bug or a feature.

Answer (score 2):

Do not try to install Tor Browser into global directories, these require Administrator permissions to write to.

Instead install it to somewhere that your user account owns, like your Desktop or a similar location, this avoids the requirement for administrator privileges. Nothing about using Tor Browser should require administrator privileges and it would be needlessly dangerous to provide it them.

Answer (score 1):

replace your tor installation file (.exe file) to some where else not in downloads (or) driver C (Local Disk C) it helped me

Comment: I just changed the installation directory into c:\Tor
it was done and resolved

Comment: exactly, because I have had One Drive sync, some directories and files have been synced with my current hard drive. So, it seems I tried reinstalling my tor on the same path. So, it has worked out, thank you